# How do I dump an object's fields to the console?

Tags: ruby, printf-debugging

When I'm running a simple Ruby script, what's the easiest way to dump an object's fields to the console?

I'm looking for something similar to PHP's `print_r()` that will work with arrays as well.

Answer (score 493, accepted):

Possibly:

```
puts variable.inspect
```

Comment: Adding an [`inspect`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/Object.html#M000225) method to your class allows you to define how the class' attributes are displayed, rather than rely on default output. A lot of classes don't implement it well, but it can be really useful when debugging. Ruby will fall back to `to_s` if it can't find an inspect` method.

Comment: Current link is broken, See this one http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-inspect

Comment: `server = TCPServer.new 0 ; puts server.inspect #<TCPServer:fd 9> => nil `. it won't work for most complex objects.

Comment: As this is the first answer found when looking  for a php `var_dump` equivalent in ruby, i found that `pp` is much usaful in that case, look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501506/ruby-inspect-readability/6501569#6501569

Comment: Note that `p object` is an [alias](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html#method-i-p) for `puts object.inspect`

Comment: `inspect` works great for attributes, but @dylanfm's answer is better if you want to see methods

Answer (score 61):

You might find a use for the `methods` method which returns an array of methods for an object. It's not the same as `print_r`, but still useful at times.

```
>> "Hello".methods.sort
=> ["%", "*", "+", "<", "<<", "<=", "<=>", "==", "===", "=~", ">", ">=", "[]", "[]=", "__id__", "__send__", "all?", "any?", "between?", "capitalize", "capitalize!", "casecmp", "center", "chomp", "chomp!", "chop", "chop!", "class", "clone", "collect", "concat", "count", "crypt", "delete", "delete!", "detect", "display", "downcase", "downcase!", "dump", "dup", "each", "each_byte", "each_line", "each_with_index", "empty?", "entries", "eql?", "equal?", "extend", "find", "find_all", "freeze", "frozen?", "grep", "gsub", "gsub!", "hash", "hex", "id", "include?", "index", "inject", "insert", "inspect", "instance_eval", "instance_of?", "instance_variable_defined?", "instance_variable_get", "instance_variable_set", "instance_variables", "intern", "is_a?", "is_binary_data?", "is_complex_yaml?", "kind_of?", "length", "ljust", "lstrip", "lstrip!", "map", "match", "max", "member?", "method", "methods", "min", "next", "next!", "nil?", "object_id", "oct", "partition", "private_methods", "protected_methods", "public_methods", "reject", "replace", "respond_to?", "reverse", "reverse!", "rindex", "rjust", "rstrip", "rstrip!", "scan", "select", "send", "singleton_methods", "size", "slice", "slice!", "sort", "sort_by", "split", "squeeze", "squeeze!", "strip", "strip!", "sub", "sub!", "succ", "succ!", "sum", "swapcase", "swapcase!", "taguri", "taguri=", "taint", "tainted?", "to_a", "to_f", "to_i", "to_s", "to_str", "to_sym", "to_yaml", "to_yaml_properties", "to_yaml_style", "tr", "tr!", "tr_s", "tr_s!", "type", "unpack", "untaint", "upcase", "upcase!", "upto", "zip"]
```

Comment: Using introspection is part of the fun of Ruby. It's often useful to subtract an Object's `instance_methods` from the class' in question to get the methods that are unique: `(String.instance_methods - Object.instance_methods).sort`

Comment: this should be the correct answer as I was expecting this when finding this page.

Comment: `.methods.sort` is very useful. Is there any 'smart' way to quickly show methods that are (vaguely) unique to that particular object? E.g. a method like `.to_s` might show up often so it's not all that useful, but some it could be very handy to know of certain methods for certain objects. Especially in cases that aren't obvious. Is there any way to quickly get these? (case in point, I have a `PG::Result` object, and want to quickly assess the likely methods I could possibly find useful.

Comment: You can also distinguish between `private_methods`, `public_methods`, and `protected_methods`, if helpful (as well as `private_instance_methods`, `public_instance_methods`, `protected_instance_methods`).

Answer (score 58):

The `to_yaml` method seems to be useful sometimes:

```
$foo = {:name => "Clem", :age => 43}

puts $foo.to_yaml
```

returns

```
--- 
:age: 43
:name: Clem
```

(Does this depend on some `YAML` module being loaded? Or would that typically be available?)

Comment: Yes, `to_yaml` requires the YAML model to be loaded. It is part of the Ruby standard library, though.

Comment: this was helpful when I was trying to inspect an Amazon S3 object in a Rails app console.

Comment: +1 because `to_yaml` is much prettier than `inspect`, -1 because `to_yaml` doesn't include anything about methods (class or instance)

Answer (score 33):

```
p object
```

[Ruby doc for `p`.](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-p)

> [`p(*args) public`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/p)
>
> For each object, directly writes obj.inspect followed
>   by a newline to the program’s standard output.

Comment: Isn't that the same as variable.to_s? I've found that just prints an object reference unless the class explicitly overrides it

Answer (score 19):

If you're looking for just the instance variables in the object, this might be useful:

```
obj.instance_variables.each do |var|
  puts [var, obj.instance_variable_get(var).inspect].join(":")
end
```

or as a one-liner for copy and pasting:

```
obj.instance_variables.each{ |var| puts [var, obj.instance_variable_get(var).inspect].join(":")}
```

Answer (score 12):

puts foo.to_json

might come in handy since the json module is loaded by default

Comment: `to_json` isn't loaded by default in 1.8.7 or 1.9.2.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to print an already **indented JSON**:

```
require 'json'
...
puts JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(object.to_json))
```

Answer (score 5):

I came across this thread because I was looking for something similar. I like the responses and they gave me some ideas so I tested the .to_hash method and worked really well for the use case too. soo:

`object.to_hash`

Answer (score 4):

```
object.attribute_names

# => ["id", "name", "email", "created_at", "updated_at", "password_digest", "remember_token", "admin", "marketing_permissions", "terms_and_conditions", "disable", "black_list", "zero_cost", "password_reset_token", "password_reset_sent_at"]


object.attributes.values

# => [1, "tom", "tom@tom.com", Tue, 02 Jun 2015 00:16:03 UTC +00:00, Tue, 02 Jun 2015 00:22:35 UTC +00:00, "$2a$10$gUTr3lpHzXvCDhVvizo8Gu/MxiTrazOWmOQqJXMW8gFLvwDftF9Lm", "2dd1829c9fb3af2a36a970acda0efe5c1d471199", true, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

Comment: `undefined method 'attributes' for ...`

Comment: `object.attributes_name` didn't work, but `object.attributes` does to get a nice hash of keys and values. This helped me out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

pp File.stat('/tmp')

```
#<File::Stat
 dev=0x1000004,
 ino=71426291,
 mode=041777 (directory rwxrwxrwt),
 nlink=15,
 uid=0 (root),
 gid=0 (wheel),
 rdev=0x0 (0, 0),
 size=480,
 blksize=4096,
 blocks=0,
 atime=2021-04-20 17:50:33.062419819 +0800 (1618912233),
 mtime=2021-04-21 11:35:32.808546288 +0800 (1618976132),
 ctime=2021-04-21 11:35:32.808546288 +0800 (1618976132)>
```

Comment: It is better if you can provide some context to your answer so that other users can understand your approach easily.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using own solution to print and debug variables is https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/wrapped_print

you can simply call `user.wp`  to see in the logs a value of this variable

instead of:

```rb
puts "-"*10
puts user.inspect
puts "-"*10
```