# Ruby Inspect readability?

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to make the output of inspect more readable?

In Perl, there is `Data::Dumper` which makes the output more easy to read.

Answer (score 39):

The ruby standard library contains PP (short for "Pretty Print"), which formats structures much better than the standard inspect:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/pp/rdoc/index.html

You need to `require 'pp'` at the top of your source file before you can use it, and then just replace `p obj` with `pp obj` in your code.

I find it really useful for hashes and arrays in particular!

Comment: PP will also add pretty_inspect() to the Kernel Module, so you can simply replace calls to inspect() with that.

Answer (score 9):

like @tjbp said, just simply use `pretty_inspect()` instead of `inspect()`

it will give you nice line break and indentation

Answer (score 8):

Beside the 'pp' solution, yaml may be a solution.

Try:

```
require 'yaml'
puts [1,2,3=>'three'].to_yaml
```

You get:

```
--- 
- 1
- 2
- 3: three
```

And a complete different approach: Write your own inspect-code if you have a inspect-problem with a specific class

Example:

```
class MyTest
  def initialize()
    @created = Time.now
  end
  def inspect()
    "Hi, I'm the objected created at #{@created}. That's #{Time.now - @created} seconds ago"
  end
end

x = MyTest.new
sleep 5
puts x.inspect
```

You get

```
Hi, I'm the objected created at 2011-06-28 12:48:38 +0100. That's 5.0 seconds ago
```

Comment: I like this solution best. I don't even have to require 'yaml' when using rails console.  Thanks for posting

Comment: YAML is the way to go!

Answer (score 6):

Try awesome_print:
http://www.rubyinside.com/awesome_print-a-new-pretty-printer-for-your-ruby-objects-3208.html

Answer (score 0):

This will work and look great :)

in your gemfile:

```
group :development do
  gem 'table_print', '~> 1.5.3'
end
```

in your view:

```
<pre>
<%= TablePrint::Printer.new(@users, []).table_print %>
</pre>
```